# Как правильно прочитать документацию (синопсис) bash команд?

Tags: unix, shell, terminal

Здравствуйте, решил поизучать команды bash и сразу столкнулся с проблемой документации. Например, хочу прочитать про команду `git`, пишу в консоли `man git` и вижу следующее:

[image: консоль]

Как правильно прочитать шаблон в секции SYNOPSIS, ну то есть что означают `[]`, `<>` и т.д.? Я поверхностно понимаю, что они означают, но где можно подробно прочитать об этом (желательно из официальных источников)?

Comment: `[]` не обязательный параметр `<>` обязательный

Comment: Поправлю коллегу:  без [] обязательный параметр; между <> подстановка одного из многих, например. push, pull и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
man man
```

.

```
   Conventional  section  names  include  NAME, SYNOPSIS, CONFIGURATION, DESCRIPTION, OPTIONS, EXIT STATUS, RETURN VALUE, ERRORS, ENVIRONMENT, FILES, VERSIONS,
   CONFORMING TO, NOTES, BUGS, EXAMPLE, AUTHORS, and SEE ALSO.

   The following conventions apply to the SYNOPSIS section and can be used as a guide in other sections.

   bold text          type exactly as shown.
   italic text        replace with appropriate argument.
   [-abc]             any or all arguments within [ ] are optional.
   -a|-b              options delimited by | cannot be used together.
   argument ...       argument is repeatable.
   [expression] ...   entire expression within [ ] is repeatable.

   Exact rendering may vary depending on the output device.  For instance, man will usually not be able to render italics when running in a terminal, and  will
   typically use underlined or coloured text instead.
```

Comment: такую команду я тоже запускал, но у меня не высвечивается, то что Вы указали в ответе, у меня макос, запускаю консоль через прогу terminal или iTerm

Comment: @mars Судя по всему, пользователям macOS за синтаксисом надо идти в [`man 5 manpages`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/manpages), в секцию `MANUAL PAGE SYNTAX`.

Comment: @Ainar-G Такой команды у меня не существует. Побродив по форуму Apple, выяснилось, что этой команды (файла) больше нету в новых версиях macOs. Но спасибо за ссылку на ее веб версию! Хотя бы там можно почитать

Comment: Они убрали man? Тогда какое отношение имеет макось к unix и shell?